# Issue with Sequelize migration - "No database selected" error

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

**Title:**
Issue with Sequelize migration - "No database selected" error

**Description:**
I'm currently facing an issue with Sequelize migrations. When I try to run `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`, I encounter a "No database selected" error. I have checked my Sequelize configuration, and it seems correct.

This is the error I get:

Sequelize CLI [Node: 20.11.1, CLI: 6.5.2, ORM: 6.35.2]

Loaded configuration file "src\config\config.cjs".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: (conn=33, no: 1046, SQLState: 3D000) No database selected
sql: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; - parameters:[]

This is the migration code:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Restaurants', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
      },
      address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      postalCode: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      url: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      shippingCosts: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      averageServiceTime: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      logo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      heroImage: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('online', 'offline', 'closed', 'temporarily closed'),
        allowNull: false
      },
      restaurantCategoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'RestaurantCategories'
          },
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'Users'
          },
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: new Date()
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: new Date()
      }
    })
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Restaurants')
  }
}
```

This is my connection configuration file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    appPort: process.env.APP_PORT,
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    dialectOptions: {
      allowPublicKeyRetrieval: true
    },
    logging: false
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    dialectOptions: {
      allowPublicKeyRetrieval: true
    },
    logging: false
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    dialectOptions: {
      allowPublicKeyRetrieval: true
    },
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tried any succesful possible solution, since I don't have much knowledge with migrations

Comment: What does your database connection configuration look like?

Comment: @Pointy I just added the config script

Comment: check in your .env file what is the value of your process.env.DATABASE_NAME key (dont post the env file here, as it contains sensitive information) but I think the value might be missing

Comment: @DanielCruz don't worry about the data since is just data for a school proyect